# Why is SQL Server using index scan instead of index seek when WHERE clause contains parameterized values

Tags: sql-server, indexing

We have found that SQL Server is using an index scan instead of an index seek if the `where` clause contains parametrized values instead of string literal.

Following is an example:

SQL Server performs index scan in following case (parameters in where clause)

```
declare @val1 nvarchar(40), @val2 nvarchar(40);
set @val1 = 'val1';
set @val2 = 'val2';

select 
    min(id) 
from 
    scor_inv_binaries 
where 
    col1 in (@val1, @val2) 
group by 
    col1
```

On the other hand, the following query performs an index seek:

```
select 
    min(id) 
from 
    scor_inv_binaries 
where 
    col1 in ('val1', 'val2') 
group by 
    col1
```

Has any one observed similar behavior, and how they have fixed this to ensure that query performs index seek instead of index scan?

We are not able to use forceseek table hint, because forceseek is supported on SQL Sserver 2005.

I have updated the statistics as well.
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: try to use INDEX hint if you are on 2005

Comment: Try adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to your SELECT

Comment: The query optimizer is likely not taking your specific parameter values into account and thus creates a worst-case query execution plan. Try using `OPTIMIZE FOR @val1 = <value>` query hints - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx.

Answer (score 20):

Well to answer your question why SQL Server is doing this, the answer is that the query is not compiled in a logical order, each statement is compiled on it's own merit,
so when the query plan for your select statement is being generated, the optimiser does not know that @val1 and @Val2 will become 'val1' and 'val2' respectively.

When SQL Server does not know the value, it has to make a best guess about how many times that variable will appear in the table, which can sometimes lead to sub-optimal plans. My main point is that the same query with different values can generate different plans. Imagine this simple example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Val INT NOT NULL, Filler CHAR(1000) NULL);
INSERT #T (Val)
SELECT  TOP 991 1
FROM    sys.all_objects a
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 9 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) + 1
FROM    sys.all_objects a;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T__Val ON #T (Val);
```

All I have done here is create a simple table, and add 1000 rows with values 1-10 for the column `val`, however 1 appears 991 times, and the other 9 only appear once. The premise being this query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    #T
WHERE   Val = 1;
```

Would be more efficient to just scan the entire table, than use the index for a seek, then do 991 bookmark lookups to get the value for `Filler`, however with only 1 row the following query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    #T
WHERE   Val = 2;
```

will be more efficient to do an index seek, and a single bookmark lookup to get the value for `Filler` (and running these two queries will ratify this)

I am pretty certain the cut off for a seek and bookmark lookup actually varies depending on the situation, but it is fairly low. Using the example table, with a bit of trial and error, I found that I needed the `Val` column to have 38 rows with the value 2 before the optimiser went for a full table scan over an index seek and bookmark lookup:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

DECLARE @I INT = 38;

CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Val INT NOT NULL, Filler CHAR(1000) NULL);
INSERT #T (Val)
SELECT  TOP (991 - @i) 1
FROM    sys.all_objects a
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP (@i) 2
FROM    sys.all_objects a
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 8 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) + 2
FROM    sys.all_objects a;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T__Val ON #T (Val);

SELECT  COUNT(Filler), COUNT(*)
FROM    #T
WHERE   Val = 2;
```

So for this example the limit is 3.7% of matching rows.

Since the query does not know the how many rows will match when you are using a variable it has to guess, and the simplest way is by finding out the total number rows, and dividing this by the total number of distinct values in the column, so in this example the estimated number of rows for `WHERE val = @Val` is 1000 / 10 = 100, The actual algorithm is more complex than this, but for example's sake this will do. So when we look at the execution plan for:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 2;
SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    #T
WHERE   Val = @i;
```

[image]

We can see here (with the original data) that the estimated number of rows is 100, but the actual rows is 1. From the previous steps we know that with more than 38 rows the optimiser will opt for a clustered index scan over an index seek, so since the best guess for the number of rows is higher than this, the plan for an unknown variable is a clustered index scan.

Just to further prove the theory, if we create the table with 1000 rows of numbers 1-27 evenly distributed (so the estimated row count will be approximately 1000 / 27 = 37.037)

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Val INT NOT NULL, Filler CHAR(1000) NULL);
INSERT #T (Val)
SELECT  TOP 27 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id)
FROM    sys.all_objects a;

INSERT #T (val)
SELECT  TOP 973 t1.Val
FROM    #T AS t1
        CROSS JOIN #T AS t2
        CROSS JOIN #T AS t3
ORDER BY t2.Val, t3.Val;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T__Val ON #T (Val);
```

Then run the query again, we get a plan with an index seek:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 2;
SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    #T
WHERE   Val = @i;
```

[image]

So hopefully that pretty comprehensively covers why you get that plan. Now I suppose the next question is how do you force a different plan, and the answer is, to use the query hint `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, to force the query to compile at execution time when the value of the parameter is known. Reverting to the original data, where the best plan for `Val = 2` is a lookup, but using a variable yields a plan with an index scan, we can run:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 2;
SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    #T
WHERE   Val = @i;

GO

DECLARE @i INT = 2;
SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    #T
WHERE   Val = @i
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

[image]

We can see that the latter uses the index seek and key lookup because it has checked the value of variable at execution time, and the most appropriate plan for that specific value is chosen. The trouble with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is that means you can't take advantage of cached query plans, so there is an additional cost of compiling the query each time.

Comment: I had something very similar, and adding the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` did not result in a change to the displayed estimated execution plan (still Table Scan), but in practice, running it with that OPTION took it to the near-instant results that I was getting when using literal values for comparison.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and none of query option solutions seemed to have any effect.

Turned out I was declaring an **n**varchar(8) as the parameter and the table had a column of varchar(8).

Upon changing the parameter type, the query did an index seek and ran instantaneously. Must be the optimizer was getting messed up by the conversion.

This may not be the answer in this case, but something that's worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
declare @val1 nvarchar(40), @val2 nvarchar(40);
set @val1 = 'val1';
set @val2 = 'val2';

select 
    min(id) 
from 
    scor_inv_binaries 
where 
    col1 in (@val1, @val2) 
group by 
    col1
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

What datatype is col1?

Your variables are nvarchar whereas your literals are varchar/char; if col1 is varchar/char it may be doing the index scan to implicitly cast each value in col1 to nvarchar for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I guess first query is using predicate and second query is using seek predicate.

Seek Predicate is the operation that describes the b-tree portion of the Seek. Predicate is the operation that describes the additional filter using non-key columns. Based on the description, it is very clear that Seek Predicate is better than Predicate as it searches indexes whereas in Predicate, the search is on non-key columns – which implies that the search is on the data in page files itself.

For more details please visit:-
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/36a176c8-005e-4a7d-afc2-68071f33987a/predicate-and-seek-predicate