# SELECT clause column causes index not being used

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried to index a table today and noticed something *awkward* and couldn't understand the reason (even if it seems so simple?). I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [X].[A](
    [TableName] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Header] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [Trailer] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [date] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Let's assume that I have a query like this (I simplified it a bit):

```
SELECT 
    Header
FROM
    X.A ht (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    ht.TableName = 'asd' AND
    '2017-05-29' BETWEEN ht.StartDate AND ht.EndDate
```

I wanted to put an index to `(TableName, StartDate, EndDate)` since they are in the where clause. My index is below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20170530-113847] ON [X].[A]
(
    [TableName] ASC,
    [StartDate] ASC,
    [EndDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

But I noticed that my query was not using the index and it does a `Table Scan`, but when I change the `SELECT` clause like the following:

```
SELECT 
    TableName
FROM
    X.A ht (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    ht.TableName = 'asd' AND
    '2017-05-29' BETWEEN ht.StartDate AND ht.EndDate
```

It does use my index and does `Index Seek` which is what I want. What's going on?

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but how many records are in your table?  I know that sometimes for smaller tables an index might not be beneficial and a full scan might instead be used.

Comment: You could use `include` to make sure the index is used in the first query (for the `header` column). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns Adding a `include (header)` to your index definition changes the query plan to use an index seek instead of table scan.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there is not much records in the table currently but there will be in the future. But why does it use the index when trying to select a column in the index then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a really simplified example, if your table had data like this:

```
ID | TableName | Header | Trailer | FileName | StartDate  | EndDate
---+-----------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------
 1 |    asd    |   H1   |    T1   |    F1    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30
 2 |    asd    |   H2   |    T2   |    F2    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30
 3 |    asd    |   H3   |    T3   |    F3    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30
 4 |    asd    |   H4   |    T4   |    F4    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30
 5 |    asd    |   H5   |    T5   |    F5    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30
 6 |    asd    |   H6   |    T6   |    F6    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30
 7 |    asd    |   H7   |    T7   |    F7    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30
 8 |    xyz    |   H1   |    T1   |    F1    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30
```

Then your index would look something like this

```
TableName | StartDate  | EndDate    | ID | 
----------+------------+------------+----+-
   asd    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30 |  1 | 
   asd    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30 |  2 | 
   asd    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30 |  3 | 
   asd    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30 |  4 | 
   asd    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30 |  5 | 
   asd    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30 |  6 | 
   asd    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30 |  7 | 
   xyz    | 2017-05-28 | 2017-05-30 |  8 |
```

In this case you can get back all the columns required for this query:

```
SELECT 
    TableName
FROM
    X.A ht (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    ht.TableName = 'asd' AND
    '2017-05-29' BETWEEN ht.StartDate AND ht.EndDate
```

But, if you want to select `Header` then you can't just use the index (since `Header`) is not stored in the index, for each row you have to find the clustering key (which in this simple example is `ID`), then lookup the corresponding row in the main table to get the value of `Header`. This (Index Seek + Key Lookup) is an expensive operation, and since you have to do this for 9 rows, and the original table only includes 10, it is probably more efficient to simple search the main table in the first place and not use the index (Clustered Index Scan).

Had you been looking up a very small number of records, like `xyd`, then it is likely that an index seek along with key lookup would have been chosen. I don't think there is a simple cut off for how many records are needed to switch between the two methods, but [in an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27566881/1048425) I found a cut off value of 3.7% of records, on a fairly small table. I expect as the table size increases this percentage decreases.

Comment: "This (Index Seek + Key Lookup) is an expensive operation, and since you have to do this for 9 rows, and the original table only includes 10, it is probably more efficient to simple search the main table in the first place and not use the index (Clustered Index Scan)." Thank you.

Comment: But what about if the table has no clustered index? Would it change anything? (assume there is no `ID`)

Comment: If there is no clustered index then SQL Server will use a row identifier in the non clustered index rather than the ID (which is just a pointer to the page & row of the full record), so the operation is very similar, as to whether it is more efficient, then this is a decent article on it -  [Is a RID Lookup faster than a Key Lookup?](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/05/sql-indexes/rid-lookup-faster-key-lookup)

Answer (score 0):

Your index covers the columns you are filtering on, but not the columns that you want to return.  This means that the query still has to scan the table to get the `RowID` of the rows that match your filtering in order to return your `Header` value.

If you add an `include` to your index that covers the `Header` column you should get the seek you are after:

```
create nonclustered index [NonClusteredIndex-20170530-113847]
on [X].[A]([TableName] asc,[StartDate] asc,[EndDate] asc)
include([Header])
with (pad_index = off,statistics_norecompute = off,sort_in_tempdb = off,drop_existing = off,online = off,allow_row_locks = on,allow_page_locks = on)
```

Comment: I most of the time thought that using `INCLUDE` is only necessary for the data types that's not supported or for long `varchar` values etc. But why Table Scan? If filtered columns are in the index, then SQL Server can pinpoint the record's location and if the `SELECT` columns are not in the index, than just go to that location and get it? Why scan the whole table? Is my index doesn't have any value for this query?

Comment: @sotn  Without including the values you want to return to your query in your index, the index has to go to the table to get them.  The `include` statement is used to include values that the index isn't sorted on to save having to go into the table when using the index.  In short, your understanding of what `include` is for is flawed.  I advise doing some research.