# Date Parameter causing Clustered Index Scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan, query-tuning

I have the following query

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2017-09-22'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2017-09-23'

SELECT a.col1,
       a.col2,
       b.col1,
       b.col2,
       b.col3,
       a.col3
FROM   TableA a
       JOIN TableB b
           ON b.pred = a.pred
WHERE  b.col2 > @StartDate AND b.col2 < @EndDate
```

When I run this and inspect the actual execution plan, I can see that the most costly operator is a clustered index scan (The index is on a.pred)

However, if I change the query as follows

```
SELECT a.col1,
       a.col2,
       b.col1,
       b.col2,
       b.col3,
       a.col3
FROM   TableA a
       JOIN TableB b
           ON b.pred = a.pred
WHERE  b.col2 > '2017-09-22' AND b.col2 < '2017-09-23'
```

The index scan is eliminated and an index seek is used.

Can someone explain why this is? In my mind, this is something to do with the fact that the value in the variable could be anything so SQL doesn't know how plan the execution.

Is there any way I can eliminate the table scan but still have use of the variable? (PS, this will be converted to a stored procedure which takes @StartDate and @EndDate as parameters)

**EDIT**

col2 is DATETIME, however, if I make my variable DATETIME the problem still persists

Comment: that is weird ... is col2 type DATE ?

Comment: Try your query with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` and do you get the index seek?

Comment: Please take a look at this [Index Scan on Parameterized values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564852/why-is-sql-server-using-index-scan-instead-of-index-seek-when-where-clause-conta)

Comment: Thanks @SQLChao that has fixed it. I'll have a read of the link from Joby as that seems to cover how it works in detail. Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you search for parameter sniffing there's a lot of articles that go into great detail which can help especially since you will be using a stored proc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is SQL Server using index scan instead of index seek when WHERE clause contains parameterized values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564852/why-is-sql-server-using-index-scan-instead-of-index-seek-when-where-clause-conta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL makes plans reusable for variables.

When you use variables - it compiles query without knowing actual values you'll pass. Even in this `sql batch` values are known. **But** it won't need to recompile query for another set of passing arguments.

So if you hardcode values - DB compiles it chosing the plan optimized for these particular values (e.g., it guesses expected number of rows passed date check). It'd be 'at least not worse' than when you use variables. But DB needs to recompile it for another set of hardcoded values (because text of the query is changed), which takes time and litters `compiled query cache` storage superseding the other useful queries.

As of:

> Is there any way I can eliminate the table scan but still have use of the variable? (PS, this will be converted to a stored procedure which takes @StartDate and @EndDate as parameters)

I think non-clustered index on `b.col2` maybe be the solution. The key of this index may also contain b.pred as a part of surrogate key or as including (`with include(pred)`).

Answer (score 0):

This query has variables, the advice in this question about sql server not knowing the value of your variables and therefore has to develop a plan based on guessed size of the result set is relevant to your question.

[Why is SQL Server using index scan instead of index seek when WHERE clause contains parameterized values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564852/why-is-sql-server-using-index-scan-instead-of-index-seek-when-where-clause-conta)

However, you mentioned that you are going to convert this code to a stored procedure.  At the time of converting it to a stored procedure the query optimizer should be able to sniff the value of the variables and develop and execution plan off of them.  Try converting it to a sproc and executing it.  The query plan should improve under those conditions.